# CSS only tooltips, doesn't work in Chrome 12.0.742.30 dev

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm currently looking into this way of doing CSS only tooltips:

http://downloads.sixrevisions.com/css-tooltips/index.html

The way this works is to move the tooltip off screen with margin-left, and then move it on screen when the tooltip target is hovered.

The approach works fine in FF, IE & Safari, however the tooltips don't show in Chrome.

When I hover over the tooltip-target, the margin-left doesn't change when I check in Developer Tools.

Anyone know if this could be modified to work in Chrome?

**Update:** This error is only occuring in Chrome 12.0.742.30 dev.

Comment: Well the link posted above works in Chrome so there is obviously something wrong with your code. Seeing some of it might help.

Comment: It doesn't work in the Chrome I'm using - version 12.0.742.30.

Comment: I'm using 11.0.696.65, haven't downloaded the beta so can't really test in that. I wouldn't be trying to get stuff working in beta versions of products, I'd tell the product developer that they broke a legacy feature and have them fix it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Comment: OK, thx - wasn't aware that I had the dev build. :)

Comment: @timkl, yes you were! look at title you wrote. ;)

Comment: Wow nice work man, looks amazing. Don't care about the beta/dev versions of the browsers. Looks awesome

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the problem altogether by not using `margin-left` to implement these tooltips.  Try using `display:none` and `display:block` instead.  This way, the element never has to move - only its visibility changes.